# Access token expires after 1 day

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, rest-api, token

I am using the Quickbooks API for my application and I have used

https://intuit.github.io/QuickBooks-V3-PHP-SDK/authorization.html

## generate-oauth-2-0-tokens for token generation.

The token is created successfully and I am able to use the token for updating Quickbooks. The problem is that after 1 day I receive the following error:

Refresh OAuth 2 Access token with Refresh Token failed. Body:

```
[{"error":"invalid_grant"}]
```

.

Comment: have you found any solution for this? even i am facing the same error message

Comment: Yes. On the next day when i request for the resource, it used to send a resource as well as new refresh token. I had to check if in the request is there any refresh token send. If yes then store in DB. This way it would become life time.

Answer (score 0):

Only exchange access tokens one at a time. If two attempts are made to exchange for access tokens, the first attempt will succeed but the second will return invalid_grant.

The servers may see this as a possible security issue and revoke your refresh tokens for the first successful call. Your next attempt to refresh tokens will return the invalid_grant error. At this point, you’ll need to start the authorization process from the beginning.